# Jmeter not run different requests that mentioned in user defined variable - Two thread groups scenario

Tags: jmeter

I have an issue that I am trying to solve with Jmeter.
I created a test plan with Http request + parameter from user defined variable.
One request with id: 11001254.
I duplicate the thread group and put in user defined variable ID = 11001419.
I run them together and saw in the results that Jmeter took the ID 11001254 and run it with both threadgroups.
even in user-defined variable it with different value?
How can I tell Jmeter to run in each thread group its own user defined variable?
all test is 20 minutes, and to run them one by one is hour.

[image]
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyMk5.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding first step a sampler of JSSR223.
and insert variables manually in script